# Add click event on an option in html select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html dropdown defined as

```
<select name="evidence_selected"id="evidence_selected">
<option id="a">A</option>
<option id="b">B</option>
<option id="c">C</option>
<option id="new">New</option>
</select>
```

I want to fire an on click event on "new" so that when a user clicks on it, a free form appears where they enter some other value that is not on dropdown.
The id of the form is "new_value".
I tried

```
$("#new").click(function(){
  $("new_value").show();

});
```

It seems the click event wont fire.
Any help(with code snippet) will be highly appreciated.
Regards

Comment: You can use the change event on the select and check for the #new option

Comment: You should focus on the select tag: option tag has no event handler for click events

Answer (score 2):

Selects use the change event

```
$('select').change(function () {
  if ($(this).val() === 'New') {
    // Handle new option
  }
});
```

This will trigger any time any of the options are selected.

Answer (score 0):

I advice doing something like this instead:

```
$('#evidence_selected').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "New"){
        $("#new_value").show();        
    } else {
        $("#new_value").hide();        
    }
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/ygkf3/)**

This way, the function will be triggered when the value of the select changes, but it'll only show `#new_value` if the option `<option id="new">New</option>` was selected...

Also if the ID of your form is `new_value`, you should reference it as `$("#new_value").show();` instead of `$("new_value").show();` (you're lacking the `#`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**html**

```
<select name="evidence_selected" id="evidence_selected">
<option id="a">A</option>
<option id="b">B</option>
<option id="c">C</option>
<option id="new">New</option>
</select>
```

**js**

```
$("#evidence_selected").change(function(){
    if($(this).val()=="new"){
        $("new_value").show();
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KL6C9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#evidence_selected").on('change', function() {
  var optionId = $('option:selected', this).attr('id');
  if(optionId === 'new') {
      // your action here
  }
});
```

Comment: What is `$("new_value")` here??

Comment: The OP has put it in his question. It can be anything he wishes it to be. Maybe an id, maybe an element... I have updated the answer

Comment: Your if statement causes a syntax error.

Comment: minor typo... corrected... thanks

Comment: Thank you all, this is my finam solution from gurudeb $("#evidence_selected").on('change', function() {
  var optionId = $('option:selected', this).attr('id');
  if(optionId === 'new') {
      // your action here
  }
});